# Efficient alternative to glm::rotate() with "up-" and "center-vec3" arguments?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, glm-math

i am working on a 3d-engine and i want to use an "up"-vector and a "heading"- or "center"-vector as indicators for the rotated-Position of an 3d-object.
To create a rotation-matrix for the OpenGL-shaders GLM provides the function *rotate(mat4(), radians, axis_of_rotation)*.
However, because i don't keep track of the *axis_of_rotation* nor how many *radians* a 3d-object is rotated, i can't use this function directly.
Currently i am using a custom function that looks like this:

```
mat4 altRotate(vec3 center, vec3 up) {

        GLfloat alpha_y = acos(dot(normalize(vec2(center.z, center.x)), vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)));
        if (center.x < 0.0f)
            alpha_y = -alpha_y;

        mat4 Ry = {
            cos(alpha_y),   0,                  sin(alpha_y),   0,
            0,              1,                  0,              0,
            -sin(alpha_y),  0,                  cos(alpha_y),   0,
            0,              0,                  0,              1
        };
        center = vec3(Ry * vec4(center, 1.0f));
        up = vec3(Ry * vec4(up, 1.0f));

        GLfloat alpha_x = acos(dot(normalize(vec2(center.z, center.y)), vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)));
        if (center.y > 0.0f)
            alpha_x = -alpha_x;

        mat4 Rx = {
            1,               0,                 0,              0,
            0,              cos(alpha_x),       -sin(alpha_x),  0,
            0,              sin(alpha_x),       cos(alpha_x),   0,
            0,              0,                  0,              1
        };
        center = vec3(Rx * vec4(center, 1.0f));
        up = vec3(Rx * vec4(up, 1.0f));

        GLfloat alpha_z = acos(dot(normalize(vec2(up.y, up.x)), vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)));
        if (up.x < 0.0f)
            alpha_z = -alpha_z;

        mat4 Rz = {
            cos(alpha_z),   -sin(alpha_z),      0,              0,
            sin(alpha_z),   cos(alpha_z),       0,              0,
            0,              0,                  1,              0,
            0,              0,                  0,              1
        };

        return Ry * Rx * Rz;        
    }
```

However, although i think i could improve the efficiency of this function, i have the feeling that the idea is way to unefficient for a 3d-game-engine.
I tried to understand the *lookAt*-function because what it does seems similar to my function but i didn't understand the code:

```
template <typename T, precision P>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> lookAtRH
    (
        tvec3<T, P> const & eye,
        tvec3<T, P> const & center,
        tvec3<T, P> const & up
    )
    {
        tvec3<T, P> const f(normalize(center - eye));
        tvec3<T, P> const s(normalize(cross(f, up)));
        tvec3<T, P> const u(cross(s, f));

        tmat4x4<T, P> Result(1);
        Result[0][0] = s.x;
        Result[1][0] = s.y;
        Result[2][0] = s.z;
        Result[0][1] = u.x;
        Result[1][1] = u.y;
        Result[2][1] = u.z;
        Result[0][2] =-f.x;
        Result[1][2] =-f.y;
        Result[2][2] =-f.z;
        Result[3][0] =-dot(s, eye);
        Result[3][1] =-dot(u, eye);
        Result[3][2] = dot(f, eye);
        return Result;
    }
```

My question is if there is already a function that can create a mat4 that rotates the vec3 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) to *heading* and vec3 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0) to *up* or is there at least a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That's exactly what `lookAt` does, in addition to moving the origin to `eye`. If you know linear algebra you should be able to understand the math behind it, if not then this is not a place to teach you linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my solution is to use the lookAt-code by GLM but remove the lins

```
    Result[3][0] =-dot(s, eye);
    Result[3][1] =-dot(u, eye);
    Result[3][2] = dot(f, eye);
```

and to remove the *eye* / (*position*) argument.
Works fine.
The output will be the same as *lookat(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), center, up)*.

Comment: That lines of code are there because `lookAt` translates the world-system axis to the camera (also called view-system) axis.